# Some help getting started with tidytext

Tags: r, text-mining, topic-modeling, tidytext

I have a project I'm working on in tidytext, which I'm pretty new to. My input data is currently in the form of individual .txt files in a folder. I successfully used get_sentiments() to track the positive/negative sentiments of my data, but I'm looking to do some more advanced topic modelling.

https://www.tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation

I'm trying to work off of this guide, but I'm struggling to get started. It looks like the input data you need to do topic modelling is a DocumentTermMatrix, which I'm unsure how to create. Is there a way to turn the data I currently have as individual files into this format so that I can use the methods described in that guide?

Answer (score 1):

You can read all your .txt files into a df and create a DocumentTermMatrix out of it using `tm`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readtext)
library(tm)

# make example text files
text1 <- c("hello world 77")
text2 <- c("What time is it? 23")

writeLines(text1,"./data/text1.txt")
writeLines(text2,"./data/text2.txt")

# read txt files
texts <- list.files("./data",full.names = TRUE) # you can replace this path with your folder path with the text files
readtext(texts) -> data

# transform the data to a corpus
Corpus(VectorSource(data$text)) -> corpus

# add normalizations (you can skip this or add more)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)

# make document-term matix
review_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

review_dtm
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 2, terms: 5)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 5/5
Sparsity           : 50%
Maximal term length: 5
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in faster performance and/or using tidy data principles, then you can avoid using the tm package altogether. Check out [this chapter of the book](https://www.tidytextmining.com/dtm.html) on how to convert back and forth from tidy data structures to a document-term matrix.

Here is a [guide on how to get started with topic modeling](https://juliasilge.com/blog/sherlock-holmes-stm/). After your data is in memory (I recommend using `readr::read_lines()` with text files), you would do something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(stm)
#> stm v1.3.5 successfully loaded. See ?stm for help. 
#>  Papers, resources, and other materials at structuraltopicmodel.com
library(janeaustenr)

austen_sparse <- austen_books() %>%  ## austenbooks like the output of read_lines()
    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
    anti_join(stop_words) %>%
    count(book, word) %>%
    cast_sparse(book, word, n)       ## cast_sparse() is what converts to a DTM
#> Joining, by = "word"

topic_model <- stm(austen_sparse, K = 12, verbose = FALSE, init.type = "Spectral")
summary(topic_model)
#> A topic model with 12 topics, 6 documents and a 13914 word dictionary.
#> Topic 1 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: anne, captain, elliot, lady, wentworth, charles, time 
#>       FREX: elliot, wentworth, walter, anne, russell, musgrove, louisa 
#>       Lift: acknowledgement, lyme, benwick, henrietta, musgrove, walter, kellynch 
#>       Score: elliot, wentworth, walter, russell, musgrove, anne, louisa 
#> Topic 2 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: emma, miss, harriet, weston, knightley, elton, jane 
#>       FREX: weston, knightley, elton, woodhouse, fairfax, churchill, hartfield 
#>       Lift: _broke_, elton's, bates, elton, emma's, enscombe, fairfax 
#>       Score: emma, weston, knightley, elton, woodhouse, fairfax, harriet 
#> Topic 3 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: elinor, marianne, time, dashwood, sister, edward, mother 
#>       FREX: elinor, marianne, dashwood, jennings, willoughby, brandon, ferrars 
#>       Lift: 1811, dashwoods, jennings's, palmer, barton, berkeley, brandon 
#>       Score: elinor, marianne, dashwood, jennings, willoughby, lucy, brandon 
#> Topic 4 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: fanny, crawford, miss, sir, edmund, time, thomas 
#>       FREX: crawford, edmund, bertram, norris, rushworth, mansfield, julia 
#>       Lift: _allow_, bertram, crawford, crawford's, norris, rushworth, susan 
#>       Score: fanny, crawford, edmund, thomas, bertram, norris, rushworth 
#> Topic 5 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: catherine, miss, tilney, time, isabella, thorpe, morland 
#>       FREX: tilney, catherine, thorpe, morland, isabella, allen, henry 
#>       Lift: abbeys, average, camilla, causeless, closets, convent, cravats 
#>       Score: catherine, tilney, thorpe, morland, allen, isabella, eleanor 
#> Topic 6 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: elizabeth, darcy, bennet, miss, jane, bingley, time 
#>       FREX: darcy, bennet, bingley, wickham, collins, lydia, lizzy 
#>       Lift: _accident_, lucas, bennet, bingley, bourgh, collins, darcy's 
#>       Score: darcy, elizabeth, bennet, bingley, wickham, collins, lydia 
#> Topic 7 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: catherine, miss, tilney, time, isabella, thorpe, morland 
#>       FREX: tilney, catherine, thorpe, morland, isabella, allen, henry 
#>       Lift: affrighted, andrews, average, blaize, camilla, causeless, closets 
#>       Score: catherine, tilney, thorpe, morland, allen, isabella, eleanor 
#> Topic 8 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: anne, captain, elliot, lady, wentworth, charles, time 
#>       FREX: elliot, wentworth, walter, anne, russell, musgrove, louisa 
#>       Lift: alicia, lyme, musgrove, walter, benwick, henrietta, kellynch 
#>       Score: elliot, wentworth, walter, russell, musgrove, anne, louisa 
#> Topic 9 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: catherine, miss, tilney, time, isabella, thorpe, morland 
#>       FREX: tilney, catherine, thorpe, morland, isabella, allen, henry 
#>       Lift: alps, andrews, blaize, france, gloucestershire, heroic, heroine 
#>       Score: catherine, tilney, thorpe, morland, allen, isabella, eleanor 
#> Topic 10 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: catherine, miss, tilney, time, isabella, thorpe, morland 
#>       FREX: tilney, catherine, thorpe, morland, isabella, allen, henry 
#>       Lift: antiquity, france, gloucestershire, heroic, lid, eleanor, eleanor's 
#>       Score: catherine, tilney, thorpe, morland, allen, isabella, eleanor 
#> Topic 11 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: anne, captain, elliot, lady, wentworth, charles, time 
#>       FREX: elliot, wentworth, walter, anne, russell, musgrove, louisa 
#>       Lift: archibald, lyme, walter, benwick, henrietta, kellynch, musgrove 
#>       Score: elliot, wentworth, walter, russell, musgrove, anne, louisa 
#> Topic 12 Top Words:
#>       Highest Prob: catherine, miss, tilney, time, isabella, thorpe, morland 
#>       FREX: tilney, catherine, thorpe, morland, isabella, allen, anyone's 
#>       Lift: anyone's, eleanor, eleanor's, heroine, northanger, thorpe's, thorpes 
#>       Score: catherine, tilney, thorpe, morland, allen, anyone's, isabella

tidy(topic_model)
#> # A tibble: 166,968 x 3
#>    topic term      beta
#>    <int> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1     1 1     1.18e- 4
#>  2     2 1     1.15e-19
#>  3     3 1     5.51e- 5
#>  4     4 1     1.33e-19
#>  5     5 1     4.20e- 5
#>  6     6 1     2.68e- 5
#>  7     7 1     4.20e- 5
#>  8     8 1     1.18e- 4
#>  9     9 1     4.20e- 5
#> 10    10 1     4.20e- 5
#> # … with 166,958 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>